# Create dynamic variadic list and pass it to a std::function

Tags: c++, templates, dependency-injection

Im writing a basic DI container in c++, and im trying to pass unknown amount of arguments to std::function.

```cpp
template<typename ...Args>
void test(std::function<void(Args *...)> const &function) {
    std::vector<void*> services_list(sizeof ...(Args));
    
    std::vector<size_t> hashes;
    hash_queue<Args...>(hashes);

   
    for(size_t hash: hashes) {
        services_list.push_back(services.get_service_by_hash(hash));
    }
    
    function(/* What to write here? */);

}
```

What im trying to achieve is to pass the vector services_list to the function unpacked, like you would do in javascript with the spread operator.

`function(...services_list)` is the ideal solution.

A call to `test` should look something like this:

```
test<Service1>([] (Service1* service) { })
test<Service1,Service2>([](Service1* service1, Service2* service2) {})
```

This is the services manager.

```cpp
services_manager services = [] {
    services_manager manager;

    manager.register_service(new Service1());
    manager.register_service(new Service2());

    return manager;
}();
```

Comment: Consider the case of a function with a single argument. What would you pass then? I don't see what values you are trying to pass to `function`, so it seems to me the problem you are having is more basic than dealing with variable number of arguments. If you *do* know what values to pass, then you should also know how many there are and be able to solve the problem. I think you may have just skipped a step and gotten distracted by the fact that you are using a parameter pack.

Comment: The number is not unknown is `sizeof ...(Args)`. Now what are the arguments though is more interesting, in your snippet there's nothing you can call your function with, you'd need to also take a `Args ... args` argument.

Comment: I have edited the question. Hopefully its clearer now.

Comment: Basically I'm trying to create the args arguments dynamically. and pass it to the function.

Comment: Variadic templates are resolved at compile-time, so it's not possible to dynamically generate a parameter pack. 

Instead, you have to pass a vector or other container and dispatch the items one by one.